# How to import colors.xml into dreamweaver creative cloud for Mac

Tags: macos, dreamweaver, color-scheme

Just upgraded to creative cloud and I can't figure out how to use the dark color scheme from http://wptom.com/dreamweaver/dark-coding-colorization-for-dreamweaver/ that I was using before. Saving the colors.xml over the old one does nothing. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get the answer on your question? I have the same question to ask. It's not working for me either.

Answer (score 3):

I realize the question was asked for OSX, but the answer to replace code color for Dreamweaver CC on Windows 7 is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC\configuration\CodeColoring

Rename and then replace Colors.xml with your file.

Answer (score 1):

(in OS X 10.7.5 & Adobe CC)

i put my darkcoding scheme succesfully in this hidden folder
**/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CC/nl_NL/configuration/CodeColoring**

Use Command+K in Finder 
and paste this path and change yourusername in your username. Don't forget to change nl_NL in your language-code.

By the way: after struggling with my own dark color scheme, i switched to That Web Guy's theme:
http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/a_dark_code_view_theme_for_dreamweaver/

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.8.4 and no luck! Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac:

From finder go to:
GO > Go to Folder

type: ~/Library

In the window that pops up go to:
Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CC/en_US/configuration/CodeColoring

(Replace en_US with what ever country code you are in)